# Formatting of Dates in Python with matplotlib and datetime: x axis error - float

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I try to plot a graph with a set of data. The y-axis is no problem, it's simple floats.
Problem is the x-axis: Its data is formatted by datetime to `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`. When trying to plot it occurs of course the error of no float possible... I tried quite many ways and it still wouldn't work...

So input so far are two arrays:

x is `['2016-02-05 17:14:55', '2016-02-05 17:14:51', '2016-02-05 17:14:49', ...]`.
y is `['35.764299', '20.3008', '36.94704', ...]`

Comment: have you had a look at http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo1.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you provide a [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make use mapplotlib's [`DateFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html?highlight=dateformatter#matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter):

1. Parse your date strings into `datetime` objects.
2. Convert your `datetime` objects into matplotlib numbers using [`date2num()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html?highlight=date2num#matplotlib.dates.date2num)
3. Create a `DateFormatter()` using your desired output format
4. Apply the `DataFormatter()` as the major tick format for the x-axis.
5. Also convert your float strings to actual floats.

Try the following:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

x_orig = ['2016-02-05 17:14:55', '2016-02-05 17:14:51', '2016-02-05 17:14:49']
x = [datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for d in x_orig]
y = ['35.764299', '20.3008', '36.94704']

xs = matplotlib.dates.date2num(x)
y_float = list(map(float, y))      # Convert y values to floats
hfmt = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S')

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(hfmt)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=15)
ax.plot(xs, y_float)
plt.show()
```

This would display the following:
[image: matplotlib screenshot]