# Is it possible to plot datetime objects instead of floats in python kivy garden graph?

Tags: python, datetime, graph, kivy

I am trying to plot a graph in a python app with kivy.garden.Graph, where x axis shows you dates (like from Jan 1, 2015 to Jan 1, 2018), and y axis gives you corresponding prices of some asset. But it seems the Graph widget only accepts floats for input. Is there a workaround or anything I can do to plot datetime objects on my graph?

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35338570/3788685) it may help.

Comment: Turns out [kivy.garden.matplotlib](https://github.com/kivy-garden/garden.matplotlib) is a way better tool. Thank you for the hint.